# Is it safe to inherit a C struct in C++ and pass it back into a C library?

Tags: c++, c, oop, inheritance, casting

I want to, basically, inherit a C struct in C++ (well, literally).  I have:

```
struct foo { // C-side definition
    int sz;
    /* whatever */
    // no virtual destructor, special mechanism
};

class cxx_class { 
    /* something here */
    // no virtual destructor, no need
};

class derived : public foo /*, public cxx_class */ {
    /* some other stuff here */
};
```

`derived` instances (in form of `foo*`) will be passed back to the external library which only knows and uses the `foo` part of `derived` (of course). But the problem is that (I assume) the library uses only c-style cast, which are equivalent to `reinterpret_cast` in C++, the `foo` in `derived` must be at the beginning of the memory block.

I wonder if this is defined behavior and does standard guarantee this?

---

In other words:

**EDIT:** *The two questions are not the same as pointed out by answers* and this part is not answered.

Sometimes I use `static_cast` for downcast. But some of the code uses `reinterpret_cast` Is it guaranteed the two always give the same answer?

Comment: If there's no virtual methods, why don't you just make foo the first member of derived? Then static_assert that derived is standard_layout, and that's as good a guarantee as you can get (it should work but not sure if guaranteed by the C++ standard).

Comment: The Standard does not prescibe an ABI (nor the *existence* of an ABI). You need to consult your platform documentation.

Comment: @NirFriedman, that works, and I was doing that, but derivation saves a up-cast.

Comment: @KerrekSB, The library is open source, and is compiled on the same machine, so no need to consult platform documentation.

Comment: @YiFei: Then I either misunderstood your question or the question is off: If you're asking whether the derived class base subobject is at the beginning of the complete object, then you need to look that up in the platform documentation. Being on the same machine doesn't answer that.

Comment: @KerrekSB, well, my bad... Basically you mean it's implementation-defined, right?

Comment: Just curious about padding: is it guaranteed in every case (e.g. bit fields and so on) that a c compiler uses the same padding rules for a struct than a C++ compiler, even if it is compiled on the same machine? Couldn't it be that the memory layout both binaries use is different?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. When you pass back derived into the C library, C++ will adjust the pointer

Comment: @geza, You're right, as pointed out by hvd.

Comment: @YiFei: as far as the C++ Standard is concerned, yes, but you may be lucky and your platform may very well promise to stick to a separate standard. For example, the Itanium ABI is de-facto standard on Linux and similar platforms.

Comment: @YiFei: great, problem solved :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `derived` instances (in form of `foo*`) will be passed back to the external library which only knows and uses the `foo` part of `derived` (of course).

If your functions take a `foo*`, it doesn't matter. Even if constructing your types in such a way that `foo` is not placed at the beginning of `derived`, the conversion from `derived*` to `foo*` happens in the C++ code which does know about the type layout. The external function then doesn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yah, didn't even noticed that.

Answer (score 2):

> does standard guarantee this?

No.

---

Since you have no virtual methods though, why don't you simply make `foo` the first member of `derived`?

Then check with `static_assert` that the derived class is `standard_layout`, which is a relatively good guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

The standard has no requirements about the layout of class hierarchies when multiple classes in that hierarchy have non-static data members.

Now, if `derived` and `cxx_class` are both *empty* (no non-static data members), then `derived` shall be a standard layout type in C++11+.

Comment: I don't follow this. `derived` and `foo` can both have non static members and derived can still be standard layout.

Comment: @NirFriedman: Not if they are non-static *data* members. Standard layout rules only allow one class in the hierarchy to have data members.

Comment: @NirFriedman The definition of "standard layout" precludes that. (see C++14 [class]/7.5)  "A standard-layout class is a class that: [...] either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and [...]"